# organising SQL Batch statements

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a tsql code ,which is basically bunch of insert and update statements wrapped into a Stored procedures and execute it as SP,but if one insert fails then the whole SP Fails, so is there a better way to continue executing rest of code if one insert fails.

Code is something like this:

```
Create SP As 
{
insert into Table A 
--
--

insert into Table B
--
--

Insert into Table C
--
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can enclose every insert instruction inside a TRY CATCH block

```
DECLARE @Errors TABLE(
Instruction VARCHAR(MAX),
Error VARCHAR(MAX)
)

BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO TABLE A
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
INSERT INTO @Errors VALUES ('TABLE A', ERROR_MESSAGE())
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO TABLE B
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
INSERT INTO @Errors VALUES ('TABLE B', ERROR_MESSAGE())
END CATCH

--....

SELECT * FROM @Errors
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,That certainly looks like somehthing i wanted ,but will it show the problem child i mean, the name of the table which is casuing the problem!

Comment: of course at the end of your script you can browse inside the variable @Errors to look up for instruction that failed and their related errors

Comment: Yay ,great but i m sry i forgot to mention i use SQL server 2000 where Error_Message doesnt seem to work

Comment: I have read the tags sql-server-2005 and sql-server-2008 on your question so I have thought that you where using that version of sql, sorry... I am not very handy with 2000 but I think you can use @@Error and look up inside sysmessage for the error message, something like SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysmessages WHERE error = @@ERROR